# problem with fr'string' in regexp and f-string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need use regexp with f-string, for simple code:

```
import re

def double_swap(txt, c1, c2):

result = [re.sub(fr'[{a}]', c1, c2) if a == c1 else (
   re.sub(fr'[{a}]', c2, c1) if a == c2 else a) for a in txt]
return ''.join(result)
```

results:

```
print(double_swap("aabbccc", "a", "b"))  # -> bbaaccc
print(double_swap("**##**", "*", "#"))  # -> ##**##
```

This code is working on vscode and py 3.7.3, 
but not working on server, I still have problem:

```
ERROR:   File "<string>", line 12
    result = [re.sub(fr'[{a}]', c1, c2) if a == c1 else (
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Maybe on server is old version of py?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with your code is your indentation? Perhaps you're not using python3.6.

Comment: Just use `format`, `r'[{}]'.format(a)` to check that. But mind that if you pass ``\`` or `^` there,you will get an error. You need to use `a.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("^", r"\^")`

Comment: Did you check what the version on the server *is* before asking this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or [`.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, but *I* know what to escape and what does not have to be escaped. `re.escape` escapes all non-word chars.

Comment: What is your question? "Maybe on server is old version of py?" - only you can answer that for sure. "I need use regexp with f-string" - then we can't provide alternatives.